# Unable to edit data on datasheet in Ms Access 2013 - Get write conflict

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2013

I have been tasked with converting an old ADP project to something that Access 2013 can handle.

I've imported all the forms and VBA, relinked the tables and changed the connection to an ODBC connection.

Most everything seems to be working ok, except for a datasheet in a subform on one form.

The datasheet fills properly but I can not edit the value on the datasheet, when I make a change to the single field that is displayed I get a "Write Conflict Error". The table that the datasheet is linked to does not contain any bit fields, it does have a primary key, and the field that I am editing is an integer.

Why am I not able to edit this field and how do I troubleshoot/fix this?

Comment: that question would probably get more answers on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case was that the ID field (which is also the primary key) was created as a BigInt. It seems that using ODBC the PK cannot be a BigInt rather it needs to be an int.

Now the question becomes what is going to happen if/when I change that field to an int?